# Google Sheets: How to Count Matching Values in 2 Columns

Tags: google-sheets, countif

In column D I have a list of 3 letter city codes for Person 1, for each day of the year (so 366 rows)

In column G I have a list of 3 letter city codes for Person 2, also for each day of the year.

I'd like to know the formula of how to count how many times the codes match? In other words, how many times are Person 1 and Person 2 are in the same city?

Additionally, the formula for counting how many matching days there are for each city, for example how many days they are both in 'LDN', 'BCN', and so on.

Comment: Do you mean Person 1 and Person 2 are in the same city in same day?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want the formula to count how many times Person 1 and Person 2 are in the same city on the same day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumption data is begin from row 2 and column A is indicated as day 1 to 366 so:

```
=arrayformula(sum((D2:D367=G2:G367)*1))
```

If not include blank cell:

```
=sum(filter((D2:D367=G2:G367)*1,D2:D367<>""))
```

Comment: How do I get the formula to omit blanks?

Comment: Use filter for non blank in D2:D367